# Collective-within-individual

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, exponential-distribution

Consider the collective-within-individual risk model $S = S_1 + .... + S_n$, where $S_i$ has a compound distribution with $N_i$ distributed Geometric($p$) and $X_i$ is distributed Exponential($m$) for all $i = 1,....,n$.

Show that $S$ has a compound distribution with $N$ distributed Binomial($n$, $1-p$) and X distributed Exponential($pm$).

I'm not sure how to do this. I tried using the mgf technique to get $N$ but I end up with a negative Binomial not a Binomial.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: can you explicitly show the nature of the compound distribution and how $S$, $X$, and $N$ interrelate